# Why is the $_POST array always empty, even when the URL has query string parameters?

Tags: php

I'm always receiving an empty $_POST array, what could be wrong?

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
 var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

**PHP version:** 5.6.30

**POST request from Postman:**

[image: Postman]

Comment: `$_POST != $_GET` try `var_dump($_GET);` in your php code

Comment: It's a POST request, shouldn't parameters be on $_POST?

Comment: The data you access with `$_POST` comes from the request body, where as the data from `$_GET` is read from the query string. You must specify your data in the "Body" tab of Postman, to make the request compatible with your code. It is by the way perfectly valid to use query parameters in conjunction with a POST request, it's just PHPs naming convention that makes things a bit confusing here.

Comment: Hm, I didn't know that $_POST doesn't read the query string. Good to know. Thanks @Redstone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Body tab to send any information in post field. have a look in attached screenshot for passing parameter through postman

[see the image for passing parameter through postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoKoB.png)

Comment: The problem was that I didn't know that $_POST doesn't reads from the query string. Thanks.

Comment: @Thiago I'm glad to help.